# reload a loaded jqGrid with a different table data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a page that displays a table in two different modes. In each mode I have a different set of columns. I'm using jqGrid to display the table. When I try to load the table for the second time (with same or different columns for that matter) the table will not refresh the data.

Is there a different API to reload data? Or should I use some method to clear the table first?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

using the method "GridUnload" will unload the grid and leave the original HTML table. Next call to create the grid will start from scratch with any given schema

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this same problem today.  I use jqGrid to display search results from parameters specified in one or more form fields.  I've got a click event on the search button and a keydown event on the fields themselves to capture the return key.  Both events call a function that serializes the form and creates the initial jqGrid.

In the initial grid I have the option to call the function reloadEvents when the gridCompletes:

```
gridComplete: reloadEvents
```

In the reloadEvents function I have:

```
$("#frmSearch").bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#searchList').setGridParam({url:'/model/actSearch.cfm?'+$('#frmSearch').serialize()});
        $('#searchList').trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
});

$('#btnSearch').click(function(){
    $('#searchList').setGridParam({url:'/model/actSearch.cfm?'+$('#frmSearch').serialize()}); 
    $('#searchList').trigger("reloadGrid");  
});
```

If you're loading your data in your grid a different way you can use setGridParam to change whatever you need.  The reloadGrid method is what should refresh your data based on the params you change.

Comment: What exactly is URL supposed to contain? Docs are very vague, they just say: `The url of the file that holds the request` I do not know what that means.