# jqGrid search/filter data api

Tags: api, search, filter, jqgrid

I've already read all available documentation and I cannot find a solution.

I have a calendar outside of the grid which on click returns a date. All I need to do is filter my jqGrid based on that date. Can someone point me to the correct API method?

Thanks!

Comment: Revisa este enlace (check this link)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179777/search-with-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-and-jqgrid/17195094#17195094

Answer (score 1):

You could do the filtering server-side. Attach an event to the calendar such that when the date is changed, the grid will be reloaded by data from the server. When you do the reload, pass the date to the server so that it can do filtering based upon that date.

See [reload-a-loaded-jqgrid-with-a-diffent-table-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297044/reload-a-loaded-jqgrid-with-a-diffent-table-data) for some pointers on how to reload the grid.

Comment: well that's exactly what I want to do but I don't want to reload it with different table data, I want to use exact same json call just pass search parameters, just like built in filter search modal window does

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my example here will help you:

[How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/24992322#24992322)

(I do the same thing, but filter my jqGrid data based on a textbox value, outside of the jqGrid.)