# How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box

Tags: jquery, search, filter, jqgrid

I want users to be able to filter grid data without using the intrinsic search box.

I have created two input fields for date (from and to) and now need to tell the grid to adopt this as its filter and then to request new data.

Forging a server request for grid data (bypassing the grid) and setting the grid's data to be the response data wont work - because as soon as the user tries to re-order the results or change the page etc. the grid will request new data from the server using a blank filter.

I cant seem to find grid API to achieve this - does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Revisa este enlace (check this link)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179777/search-with-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-and-jqgrid/17195094#17195094

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You problem can be very easy solved with respect of `postData` parameter including functions and `trigger('reloadGrid')`. I try explain the idea more detailed.

Let us use `mtype: "GET"`. The only thing which standard search/filter box do after displaying the interface is appending of some additional parameters to the url, sending to server and reloading the grid data. If you have your own interface for searching/filtering (some select controls or checkboxes, for example) you should just append your url yourself and reload the grid with respect of `trigger('reloadGrid')`. For resetting of the information in the grid you can choose any way which you prefer. For example, you can include in the select controls which you have an option like "no filtering".

To be more exact your code should looks like the code from the answer [how to reload jqgrid in asp.net mvc when i change dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839721/how-to-reload-jqgrid-in-asp-net-mvc-when-i-change-dropdownlist/2842199#2842199):

```
var myGrid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url: gridDataUrl,
    postData: {
        StateId: function() { return jQuery("#StateId option:selected").val(); },
        CityId: function() { return jQuery("#CityId option:selected").val(); },
        hospname: function() { return jQuery("#HospitalName").val(); }
    }
    // ...
});
//
var myReload = function() {
    myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');
};
var keyupHandler = function (e,refreshFunction,obj) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 33 /*page up*/|| keyCode === 34 /*page down*/||
        keyCode === 35 /*end*/|| keyCode === 36 /*home*/||
        keyCode === 38 /*up arrow*/|| keyCode === 40 /*down arrow*/) {

        if (typeof refreshFunction === "function") {
            refreshFunction(obj);
       }
    }
};

// ...
$("#StateId").change(myReload).keyup(function (e) {
    keyupHandler(e,myReload,this);
});
$("#CityId").change(myReload).keyup(function (e) {
    keyupHandler(e,myReload,this);
});
```

If user change selected option in select box with `id=StateId` or another select box with  `id=CityId` (with mouse or keyboard), the function `myReload` will be called, which just force  reloading of data in jqGrid. During corresponding `$.ajax` request, which jqGrid do for us, the value from `postData` parameter will be forwarded to `$.ajax` as `data` parameter. If some from properties of `data` are functions, these function will be called by `$.ajax`. So the actual data from select boxes will be loaded and all the data will be appended to the data sent to the server. You need only implement reading of this parameters in your server part.

So the data from the `postData` parameter will be appended to the url (symbols '?' and '&' will be added automatically and all special symbols like blanks will be also encoded as usual). The advantages of the usage of `postData` is:

1. **usage of functions** inside `postData` parameter allows you to load **actual** values from all used controls to the moment of reloading;
2. Your code stay have very clear structure.
3. All works fine not only with HTTP GET requests, but with HTTP POST also;

If you use some "no filtering" or "all" entries in the select box `StateId`, you can modify the function which calculate the value of `StateId` parameter which should appended to the server url from

```
StateId: function() { return jQuery("#StateId option:selected").val(); }
```

to something like following:

```
StateId: function() {
    var val = jQuery("#StateId option:selected").val();
    return val === "all"? "": val;
}
```

On the server side you should makes no filtering for `StateId` if you receive an empty value as a parameter.

Optionally you can use `myGrid.setCaption('A text');` to change a grid title. This allow user to see more clear, that the data in grid are filtered with some criteria.

Comment: @Oleg, can i override the default `postData` functions with a `grid.setGridParam`? I'm trying to do this, but with no success. It appears that even though i set a param through `grid.setGridParam` it stills get the default `postData` function i defined previously.

Comment: @AdrianoRR: Probably you should write a new question where you describe the problem which you want to solve. What you need? Do you want that some parameters will be not send to the server? Do you need custom formatting of existing parameters (like converting to JSON)? Or you probably don't want to send any additional parameters to the server?

Comment: @Oleg, by seeing some other posts of your i manage to get my own answer. By using `grid.getGridParam` i can get postData attributes and set them which any values i want. Then all i have to do is call `grid.trigger("reloadGrid");` and the changes are done. Anyway, thanks for your S.O. posts!

Comment: @AdrianoRR: You are welcome! Sorry, but I still don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to post an **additional** custom parameter or to *change in some way an existing standard parameter*? I suggested you to ask new question to give you more place to describe your problem in details and to explain what you need to implement, what information you need to send to the server and so on.

Comment: hi mr Oleg, i have problem in jqgrid searching i ask question in this address, please check my question, thanks   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309625/search-in-jqgrid

Comment: @Oleg , I don't understand myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid'); works fine, but $("#list").jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid') gives huge list of errors with 'method trigger not defined for...' at the end. Thanks for being so helpful in SO

Comment: @abhihello123: You are welcome! The usage `$("#list").jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid')` is definitively wrong. The expression `$("#list").trigger('reloadGrid')` is correct. The method [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) is common **jQuery method** which you can apply on any jQuery objects. `$("#list")` or `myGrid` are jQuery objects so you can use `trigger` method on the objects. The expression `$("#list").jqGrid` is the *method* applied on `$("#list")` object. You can use `$("#list").jqGrid({...})` or `$("#list").jqGrid("jqGridMethid", ...)`, but not `$("#list").jqGrid.trigger(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirements, and (with Oleg's help) came up with this:

[image]

Basically, the user starts typing in the "Employee name" textbox, and immediately the results get shown in the jqGrid.

Details of how I implemented this are here:

[jqGrid - Change filter/search pop up form - to be flat on page - not a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832085/jqgrid-change-filter-search-pop-up-form-to-be-flat-on-page-not-a-dialog/24528183#24528183)

Note that I specifically load *all* of the JSON data for my jqGrid *in advance*, and that for large data sets, there is a delay when running this code on an iPhone/Android device as you type each character.

But, for desktop web apps, it's a great solution, and makes jqGrid much friendler for the user.

Answer (score 0):

By using `ReloadGrid()` and `jquery` functions you can make your own custom filtering functions.